# I can't change Laravel 5.2 register

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using the default login and register form, that one who uses the `artisan make:auth` command, but I'm trying to change the table who the application going to work on, using `config/auth.php`. I have changed the login, but the register doesn't follow the customization.

The only thing that I have changed is the `provider ->'table' => 'funcionarios'`.

Comment: Maybe, you also need to change your migration.

Comment: I did it, but isn't work as well. I guess the the problem is in the route, because the artisan command "make:auth" didn't change the 'route.php', and when I try change '/register' route isn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

If route.php isn't changing then try
    php artisan route:clear

Comment: I've foud the core route file: **"Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"**. at this php file have some routes that u can't change using the **"app/Controller/route.php"**